# two conditional probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability

really stuck in here. Suppose i want to calculate this probability:

$P(S|B)$ can i use the total probability law to write:

$P(S|B) = P(S\cap H |B) + P(S\cap H^{c}|B)$ ?

and suppose i know for a fact that $S\cap H^{c} = \emptyset$

so i get the expresion: $P(S|B) = P(S\cap H |B)$

and again, can i write $P(S|B) = P(S|B,H)P(H|B)$ ??

Just to clarify, the set $H^{c}$ is the complement of H to the Universe.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think of $S$ and $H$ as events. 
Because $S\cap H^{c} = \emptyset$, it follows that if $S$ happens, $H^{c}$ does not happen, and therefore $H$ happens. So knowing $S$ happens already implies $H$, meaning $H$ does not give you any additional information here.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

Comment: so i can claim everything that i put there? Another thing came to my mind: It turns out that i know how to compute the value of $P(S | B,H)$ and $P(H|B)$. Can i declare that: $P(S | B,H) = P(S | H)$ knowing that $B \cap H = H$ ?